# How to describe an online game player and youtube watcher in a single word

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe

> the person who is spending lot of time on online games and youtube channel and not spending time on studies and home work?

Just "games addict" might not be very suitable. What's a single word for addicts of both online games and youtube? The word would be used like this:

> Such a person would be described as a __________.

Comment: I'd call that person as an "Internet addict," i.e., a person who has an Internet addiction since both their gaming activities and their YouTube activities are Internet-based.

Comment: A [**gamer**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/gamer) is *a person who plays video games or participates in role-playing games*.

Comment: For ELU, I'm afraid we need more detail in this sort of question. **Why** is "games addict" not suitable? I've retagged your question with the right ELU tag (which doesn't exist on Writers): please have a look at the [tag help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and try to make this question fit the guidance. Thanks!

Comment: andrew, online games comes under games, but watching more youtube does not come under games, some thin line is there between

Comment: There are words for people who spend a lot of time online (as with the already-mentioned "Internet addict"), and for people who indulge in (stereotypically) geeky pastimes (geek, otaku, etc). Would either fit? Watching Youtube may or may not be classed as geeky depending on what you watch.

Comment: thanks stuart for geek, otaku. that answers me. thanks I can close this question now.

Comment: If you're going to do that, please [write an answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and accept it when you can. For future requests of this sort, please follow the checklist at the end of the [guidance](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**gijutsu otaku** looks like the nearest word thanks to [Stuart’s input](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566058/how-to-describe-online-game-player-plus-youtube-watcher-in-single-word#comment1402765_566058).

[Wikipedia defines *otaku*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otaku) as follows:

> *Otaku* (Japanese: おたく, オタク, or ヲタク) is a Japanese term for people with consuming interests, particularly in anime and manga. Its
> contemporary use originated with a 1983 essay by Akio Nakamori in
> *Manga Burikko*. ... The definition of *otaku* subsequently became more
> complex, and numerous classifications of *otaku* emerged.

“a technological geek would be gijutsu otaku (技術オタク)”.

While [some online dictionaries](https://www.onelook.com/?w=otaku&ls=a) offer a definition of *otaku*, Merriam-Webster hasn't yet added it, but they do provide a [comprehensive analysis of the term](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-does-otaku-mean-in-japanese), finishing with the following:

> There remains a certain amount of disagreement on the meaning and
> politeness of *otaku*, which is hardly surprising when one considers
> that many of the people who self-define with this word are strongly
> interested in genres and highly particular fields of popular culture.
> When it's used in English, some view it as being rightfully applied to
> those whose interests are exclusively concerned with pop culture,
> while others expand it to include technology. Some feel that *otaku*
> carries the sense of “reclusive and potentially dangerous,” while
> others think it could mean “mostly harmless and quirky.”

Comment: Is this a loanword? Has it become mainstream in English?

Comment: It appears in dictionaries, but it isn't a precise answer to your question. Please note that questions for over-specified words ('a word for an online game player who is also a  Youtube watcher and has a Van-Dyck beard') are silly, and this is at least heading that way.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, I am using this word in case he is not using internet for educational purpose, but when playing games and watching unnecessary games.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A : yes as Edwin alreay confirmed and Stuart already used it